# pydev 1.5.3 not working fine with Easy Eclipse 1.3.1

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I installed Pydev 1.5.3 (so that I could get the merged version of Pydev Extensions in core PyDev) in an EasyEclipse 1.3.1 installation. After this, `Compare with > Base revision` etc. comparison operations stopped working. I had to disable the PyDev 1.5.3 and revert back to the pre-installed Pydev 1.3.13 (part of EasyEclipse 1.3.1).

Has anybody faced similar problem? Is there any work-around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am now using PyDev 1.5.6 and its working fine with EasyEclipse (along with SubClipse). The issues in comparison seem to have been resolved. In fact, the file diff in 1.5.6 is looking much more beautiful than before.

Answer (score 0):

My pydev broke entirely with 1.5.3.
I had to downgrade `yum downgrade eclipse-pydev` and keep yum from updating it ever since.